# How to fill username and password automatically for webview like browser in Android?

Tags: android, browser, webview

I would like to make an app which easier for me to accept to my web page. My web page need a username and password to log in, so I need my app could fill username and password automatically for more convenient. Please help me. Thank you. This is my code:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very effective alternative is to use the user's email address as the username and then you can create a random/generic password. Later you pass the (encrypted) data in the webview's URL via get or post.

```
    //  Email
    String email = "";

    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+

    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext()).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            email = account.name;

            break;
        }
    }
    // -
```

Remember to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

in the app manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean after log in for the first time, username and password will be save and automatically filled when the webview is opened for the second time and all times after that, same as save password on browser. I used 'webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);' but it's not effectively.

Comment: In this case forget about the java side, what you need is to save user's credentials in a cookie or session after the first time they log in, using javascript or a script language (like PHP or ASP) in the server side (your website).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it.